# How can I rewrite query parameters to path parameters in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I currently have a website that I am trying to optimize in terms of SEO.

I've got the site working with URLs such as:

> domain.com/?app=about

In my app, `$_GET[app]` is set to 'about', as expected.

Now, I want to make it so that a URL like `domain.com/about` is treated as if it were `domain.com/?app=about`.

How can I do this in an Apache .htaccess file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are known as `RewriteRule`s, and they are fairly straightforward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about$ /index.php?app=about
```

[Here's the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

As far as making it more generic, how about this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ /index.php?app=$1
```

This will make any request to something like /staff or /contact redirect to index.php?app=[staff|contact]

Comment: is there anyway to make this more generic, i.e, have a general one for all apps instead of writing one for each app?

Comment: +1 - however that example will work, but if you've got a few things to rewrite, you're better off using a more generic solution. What about `^[^/]$ index.php?app=$1` I might be incorrect in that regex but the general idea is there :P

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /your-site # only if neccessary

RewriteRule ^([^/])$ index.php?app=$1 [R,L]
```

**EDIT**

I added the L flag meaning process this as the last rule, and the R flag which by itself does not change the URL .. just rewrites internally. Doing R=301 will forward the browser to the rewritten page, which is useful for debugging.

Comment: it's getting there, but seems that something is wrong. http://thinkteen.co.uk try /contact or /staff :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a general .htaccess getting the path requested can be done with the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^((.+/)+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,B]
```

This will give you the path requested escaped properly so if the requested path is */hello/world* you will get *hello%2Fworld* in the path parameter. Use the PHP function urldecode() to get the original format.

Works only if the url ends with '/'.

**NOTE** If you have other rewrites in the same file you should place this one last as it will match basically anything.