# How to redirect with pretty and clean URL's?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When trying to redirect to www.example.com/how-to-cook-a-egg

it does not work

but if you do this wwww.example.com/viewpost.php?p=how-to-cook-a-egg

it works fine

This is what i am currently using to rewrite the URL's this worked fine on my local but once i tried on my server it did not work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)$ viewpost.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

also this url is stored in the database how-to-cook-a-egg

So what i want to happen is that when you are on the homepage of the site and clicks the www.example.com/how-to-cook-a-egg url it goes to viewpost.php and displays that post with out the viewpost.php in the url

Comment: Have you confirmed that your server is Apache HTTPD? That mod_rewrite is loaded? That Overrides are allowed by the configuration?

Comment: possiblythis post is helpful? hope so for you :) (parameter to path) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114950/how-can-i-rewrite-query-parameters-to-path-parameters-in-apache

Comment: "it does not work" does not really help here. You will need to dig yourself, since we have no knowledge about and no access to your setup. So: what http server, what version, what configuration? What does your http server's error log file say?

Comment: @arkascha Mod re-write is enabled on the server

Comment: @also this url how-to-cook-a-egg is stored in the database

Comment: And is the rewriting engine also enabled for that location inside the http server? Keep in mind that just loading the module is not enough, you need to also enable it (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation). And again I want to ask for what the http server's error log file reveals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is my fault i figured it out i had to add / to one of the RewriteRule

So before it was RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)$ viewpost.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

now it's RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)$ /viewpost.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code in your .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```